# Is there a "Super" break key for bash?

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys

When using terminal sometimes you need to break the program. Sometimes you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> sometimes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> and sometimes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>

In some circumstances, it might simply be closing a quote or pressing enter a few times there are even instances when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> will work.

So when I get stuck, like an idiot, I start mashing those keys like an idiot in the hope that the process will quit. In 95% of the cases it works and when I get desperate I just close the terminal and that works 100% of the time. I'm sure there is a logical reason for the various states due to the program being in a particular state but all I want to do is just break the application and return to the bash prompt.

Is there a super key that will break the process without having to mash these 4 magic keys in the hope that the application will terminate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The super key *is* closing the terminal. :-) That, or the power button on your computer.

Each of the key combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> does a different thing.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> : generates an interrupt signal (SIGINT).
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> : I'm not sure what this does.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> : suspend the process, allowing it to be resumed at a later point (SIGSTOP).
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> : sends an end-of-file (EOF) character.

Each process is at liberty to interpret these signals as they see fit. Hence, there is some heterogeneity in the response.

A more generic way to terminate a process would be to kill it with a SIGKILL signal, the most aggressive way, which is which (I think) is the same as closing the terminal window. It's better to attempt <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> first though, because these are signals that the process can anticipate, allowing it to end in a predictable and safer way.

Check the manual page with `man 7 signal`.

Comment: ctr-z suspend, didnt know that, how do you resume?

Comment: If there's a single process, then just type `fg`. You can also resume it in the background with `bg`. There's quite a lot you can do with this, running multiple jobs in a single terminal. Try googling "bash jobs" or similar.

Comment: Thanks, i normally use screen command for that, always wanted to know why when exiting terminal it said there were running jobs, now I know, pressed ctr-z wrongly sending it to background instead of terminating

Comment: Closing the terminal window sends SIGHUP, I believe. You should only send SIGKILL as a last resort, since it forces a program to quit without having a chance to clean up after itself. Better to send SIGTERM or even a manual SIGHUP.

Comment: @ScottSeverance Yeah, I didn't really go into SIGTERM, but I suspect that SIGINT (`Ctrl`+`c`) or EOF (`Ctrl`+`d`) are even safer? But yes, I agree that SIGTERM is better than SIGKILL.

Comment: Read this [sad story](https://turnoff.us/geek/dont-sigkill/) about why you shouldn't use SIGKILL if not necessary.